An error occurred after calling tpm2_CreatePrimary, ERROR: 0x000001D5
The message sent is:
tpm_xfer: sending buffer \[size:74\]:

80 02 00 00 00 4a 00 00 01 31 40 00 00 01 00 00

00 09 40 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00

00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 0b 00 00 00 50 00 00 00

10 00 10 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

The message received is:
tpm_xfer: received buffer \[size:10\]:

80 01 00 00 00 0a 00 00 01 d5

u32 tpm2_CreatePrimary(u32 parent_handle, u32 out_handle, u8 *pub_key, u32 *pub_key_size) {
    if (!pub_key || !pub_key_size) {
        return TPM2_RC_FAILURE; 
    }

    u32 primaryHandle = parent_handle;
    u8 pw_sz = 0;

    // inSensitive
    u8 inSensitive[] = {
        0x00, 0x0B,                 // size
        0x00, 0x00,                 // userAuth size (empty password)
        0x00, 0x00                  // data size
    };

    // inPublic (RSA 2048 key)
    u8 inPublic[] = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,     // size (placeholder)
        0x00, 0x01,                 // type (TPM2_ALG_RSA)
        0x00, 0x0B,                 // nameAlg (TPM2_ALG_SHA256)
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50,     // objectAttributes (fixed TPM, fixed parent, sensitive data origin, user with auth)
        0x00, 0x00,                 // authPolicy size
        0x00, 0x10,                 // symmetric
        0x00, 0x10,                 // scheme
        0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00,     // keyBits (2048)
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00      // exponent (0 = default 65537)
    };

    // outsideInfo and creationPCR (empty)
    u8 outsideInfo[] = {0x00, 0x00};
    u8 creationPCR[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};


    u32 commandSize = 27 + 9 + pw_sz + sizeof(inSensitive) + sizeof(inPublic) + sizeof(outsideInfo) + sizeof(creationPCR);


    u8 command[COMMAND_BUFFER_SIZE] = {
        tpm_u16(TPM2_ST_SESSIONS),       // TPM_ST_SESSIONS
        tpm_u32(commandSize),            // Command Size
        tpm_u32(TPM2_CC_CreatePrimary),  
        tpm_u32(primaryHandle),          // primaryHandle
        tpm_u32(9),                      
        tpm_u32(TPM2_RS_PW),             
        0x00, 0x00,                      // nonce size
        0x00,                            // session attributes
        0x00, 0x00                       // auth size (empty password)
    };

    tpm_debug("Command header filled");

    u32 offset = 27;
    memcpy(command + offset, inSensitive, sizeof(inSensitive));
    offset += sizeof(inSensitive);
    memcpy(command + offset, inPublic, sizeof(inPublic));
    offset += sizeof(inPublic);
    memcpy(command + offset, outsideInfo, sizeof(outsideInfo));
    offset += sizeof(outsideInfo);
    memcpy(command + offset, creationPCR, sizeof(creationPCR));


    u8 response[RESPONSE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    u32 resp_len = sizeof(response);
    u32 ret = tpm_sendrecv_command(command, response, &resp_len);

......

Why did this error occur? I couldn't find the corresponding error for 0x000001D5. Also, does the COMMAND have any other errors? Thanks.
